# Find the probability for colored ball selection

Tags: probability

A bag contains $6$ yellow balls and $5$ green balls. Then, $4$ balls are chosen at random from the bag.  Find the probability that:

(i)                No yellow ball is chosen.

(ii)               At least one yellow ball is chosen.

Comment: Are they chosen one by one or at the same time, please specify that in your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that a non-yellow ball is chosen on the first draw is 5/11.  Assuming a non-yellow ball is so chosen, then the probability that a non-yellow ball is chosen on the second draw is 4/10.  And so forth for four draws:

$Prob[no~yellows] = {5 \over 11} {4 \over 10} {3 \over 9} {2 \over 8} = 1/66$.

Prob at least one yellow = $1 - Prob[no~yellows] = 65/66$.

Comment: To solve this type of problems, we have to know how did we pick the balls

Comment: @Oussama Boussif:  Ramdomly.  It makes no difference whether they were picked one-by-one or all four at a time.

Comment: G.Stork if we calculate $card(\omega)$ we wil get three differnt values for three different scenarios unless I misunderstood the word "random"